# Resize only vertical images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, image-resizing

I have a problem with a vertical scrolling photo gallery, 
I want vertical images to resize but horizontal images are fine the way they are.
Horizontal images are 900px in width and vertical images would be too tall for confortable screen viewing so I want two 440px width vertical images and a central margin of 20px to fit below one horizontal.

The website is on Cargocollective so I can't use PHP, only Jquery, Javascript and CSS
And I can only add on the HTML.
Anyone has a solution?

A way to detect the ratio of the images and then resize only if height>width

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$('img').each(function(i,obj){
    if($(obj).height() > $(obj).width()){
        //portrait, resize accordingly  
    }else{
        //landscape display; the default you want.
    }
});
```

in jQuery 1.7 and above, we can access the property of each image without using the $.each iterator.

```
$('img').prop('height', function(){
    if($(this).height() > $(this).width()){
        //portrait, resize accordingly  
    }else{
       //landscape display; the default you want.
    }
});
```

Comment: Could also use `$(this)` instead of passing through `obj`, but that's just personal preference I guess!

Answer (score 2):

A variation of OhGodwhy's answer making sure image is loaded when height/width is being calculated.

```
$('#myElement img').load(function(){
    if($(this).height() > $(this).width()){
        //portrait, resize accordingly  
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var newWidth = 400;
        var newHeight = newWidth * (height / width);
        $(this).width(newWidth).height(newHeight);
    }else{
        //landscape display; the default you want.
    }
});
```